# search for multiple words in an option in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I use [select2](https://select2.org)
As a result, I have a list on the backend

```
[
  [12, "red fast car1"],
  [45, "red big car2"],
  [56, "red small table1"],
  [34, "red fast car3"],
  [77, "red big table"]
]
```

on request 'red car' need to get a list:

- red fast car1
- red big car2
- red fast car3

what match use for this?
My [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/958v0y1w/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the `term` at every `<space>` and return true only if [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) individual word matches the `text` and `label`

```
  const terms = term.split(' ');

  return terms.every(term => {
     if (text.indexOf(term) > -1 ||
        (label !== undefined &&
           label.toUpperCase().indexOf(term) > -1)) {
        return true;
     }
  })
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/2g1q5ypn/)

Comment: how to rewrite `every` without `=>`?

Comment: That's the [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) introduced in ES6. You can change it to ES5 code like this: `terms.every(function(term) {  ...  })`

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this topic, thanks for pointing out you can use a custom matcher in select2.

Nonetheless, [the interface seems to have changed](https://select2.org/searching#customizing-how-results-are-matched) since you wrote the fiddle, so here is the adaptation I had to write in coffeescript (⚠️ I don't use optgroups):

```coffee
$ ->
  matcher = (params, data) ->
    if !params.term?
      return data

    terms = params.term.toUpperCase().split(' ')
    text = data.text.toUpperCase()

    if terms.every((term) -> return true if text.indexOf(term) > -1)
      return data
    else
      return null


  $('.selectpicker').select2({matcher: matcher});
```

Answer (score 0):

@AlexandreS: You're a life saver mate! Your code written in coffeescript worked like a charm. For those looking for a vanilla JS, here's a code interpreted from @AlexandreS coffeescript code:

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    var matcher;
    return matcher = function(params, data) {
      var terms, text;
      if (params.term == null) {
        return data;
      }
      terms = params.term.toUpperCase().split(' ');
      text = data.text.toUpperCase();
      if (terms.every(function(term) {
        if (text.indexOf(term) > -1) {
          return true;
        }
      })) {
        return data;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };
  });

  $('.selectpicker').select2({
    matcher: matcher
  });

}).call(this);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).